# FedEx rates unavailable after upgrade from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

After upgrading a customer's site from CE 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.3, FedEx no longer returns any rates at checkout.  Everything is set up correctly, it worked great prior to the upgrade.

On SO, I noticed someone corrected this by replacing

```
app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Models/Shipping/Carriers/Fedex.php
```

with the version from 1.7.0.2, but I wasn't comfortable with it.

I didn't find the answer elsewhere on the Internets, so I decided to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the difference I noticed one thing that changed was the ability to set the unit of measure.  All I had to do was go into

```
System > Configuration > Shipping Methods
```

(make sure that Pounds or Kilograms is selected under FedEx) and Save Config.